# JQuery .click() not working maybe interfering with angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have this code on my main page:

```html
<body>
    <div id="leftMenu" ng-app=SearchApp>
     <div id="searchFoldersList"><span class="icon-search search"></span><input ng-model="searchFolder" type="text" placeholder="Search..." /></div>
     <div id="foldersList" ng-controller="empCtrl">
         <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="fold in folder | filter: searchFolder">{{fold.Folder}} <div id="editFolder_menu"><span class="icon-edit"></span></div></li>
                <li ng-show="showInputBox = !showInputBox" id="addFolderInputBox"><input ng-model="fname" name="fname" class="changeNameFolder" placeholder="New folders name..." type="text" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     <div id="addFolderBox" ng-click="showInputBox"><span class="icon-add plus"></span> ADD NEW FOLDER</div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightContent">
        <div id="menuContent">
         <ul>
             <li><span class="icon-list"></span></li>
                <li><span class="icon-settings"></span></li>
                <li><span class="icon-account-circle"></span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And this on scripts.js:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#foldersList ul li").click(function(){
 alert("HELLO");
  });
});
```

Any idea why this is not working?

I think its because something is interfering with angularJS.

Thanks!

Comment: What might be happening is you're assigning the `.click()` before the elements are all created by the `ng-repeat`. Try assigning a `ng-click` handler in angular instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of do that, add ng-click="someFunc()" to your li elements and define that someFunc as a property of the empCtrl scope

Comment: I had not thought about that, it's a great idea! Thank you so much.

Comment: One more thing, how can I add someFunc as a property of the empCtrl scope? Sorry im a newbie on AngularJS